# How to update DbContext using Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I want to update the data in my database using Entity Framework Core.

However, I get an error:

> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateConcurrencyEception: the database operation was expected to affect 1 row(s) but actually affected 0 row(s). Data may be modified or deleted since entities were loaded.

This is the code:

```
public book Update(todoList model)
{
    var data = new todoListDataModel
                   {
                        seqNo = model.seqNo,
                        customerId = model.customerId,
                        ...
                   },
    _context.TODOLIST.Update(data);

    try
    {
        var todoList = _context.TODOLIST.FirstOrDefault(u => u.seqNo == model.seqNo);
        _context.SaveChanges();
        return true;
    }
    catch (SystemException ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

This is the code that sets the content of the update.

```
public string updateCompliteFlg(string operatorId , string id)
{
    try
    {
        var model = _repository.FindById(id);
   
        model.resultFlg = "1"
        model.operatorId = operatorId;
        ...

        // Methods for storing in entities(todoList)
        var data = updateCompliteFlgToData(model, operatorId, id);

        // Call Update
        if (_repository.Update(data))
        {
            return "Update!"
        }
        else
        {
            return "Failed!"
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        return "Exception!"
    }
}
```

The "model" argument to this method is an array of contains the updated contents.

The updates are stored in "data" and TODOLIST in the DB context is updated.

What am I doing wrong? Please tell me.

Thank you.

Comment: [Identity Resolution in EF Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/change-tracking/identity-resolution). There are three ways to do an update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your update call is placed on wrong place.
Keep note that while we are updating anything first fetch the data with then modified value of same object.

You have first retrieve it from the database, then you can update it.

```
public book Update(todoList model)
{
    var todoList = _context.TODOLIST.FirstOrDefault(u => u.seqNo == model.seqNo);
    
    todoList.customerId=model.customerId

    try
    {
        _context.SaveChanges();
        return true;
    }
    catch (SystemException ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you!
I have tried the above code.
But An error has occurred.

Comment: "
The init-only property or integrator "todoListDataModel.seqNo" can only be assigned in object initializers or on 'this' or 'base' of an instance constructor or 'init' accessor.
"

Comment: The line `todoList.seqNo=model.seqNo;` is not needed, because these values are already equal by condition in `FirstOrDefault`. The line `_context.TODOLIST.Update(todoList);` is not needed, because the entity will already be marked modified when any property is changed.

Comment: @tatsuya I made some changes as per Alexnader suggestion.

Comment: @KiranJoshi


Thank you!
It seems to update only in the object initializer or in the instance constructor or in the 'init' accessor this or base, do you know?
```
todoList.customerId=model.customerId
```

Comment: It was the difference between init and set!